# Jquery empty() or remove() wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a little game for practicing jQuery and PHP.
By clicking on the right spot you'll go to the next question or you have fail.
For checking the right answer I use a Img(img of the question) with usemap

```
        <img id="questions" src="../img/items/question1.png" style="height: 450px;width: 700px;" usemap="#result">
        <map name="result">
        </map>
```

As you can see, the map has no area's.
Those I add in a script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var score = 0;

  var answer1 = '<area class="true" shape="circle" coords="145, 175, 40" href="#">';
  var entireImg = '<area class="false" shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 700, 450" href="#">';

  $(answer1).appendTo('map');
  $(entireImg).appendTo('map');

  $('.true').click(function(){
      score++;
      $('#questions').attr({src: "../img/items/question2.png"});

  });
  $('.false').click(function(){
      $('#questions').attr({src: "../img/items/fail.png"});
      $('.notes').show();
  });
});
```

If you got the right answer I add a new area with the right answer location for each question.
Now the problem I got is; I cant remove the previous answer area from the form.
**What I tried so far:**

Changing the variable with a other location an add this to to map:

```
$('.true').click(function(){
    score++;
    $('#questions').attr({src: "../img/items/question2.png"});
    answer1 = '<area class="true" shape="circle" coords="200, 300, 40" href="#">';
    $(answer1).appendTo('map');
});
```

Remove the var from the map:

```
$('.true').click(function(){
    score++;
    $('#questions').attr({src: "../img/items/question2.png"});
    $('answer1').remove();
});
```

Remove the added  element:

```
$('.true').click(function(){
    score++;
    $('<area class="true" shape="circle" coords="145, 175, 40" href="#">').remove();        
});
```

And empty the value (and empty the value and append the 'empty' value again).

Non of those work, and by the knowledge I have so far (witch is not so much) I cant figure it out (already spent like 2 hours googling around).

I put the game online on this links: 
http://i333180.iris.fhict.nl/demo/pages/index.php

Regards

Comment: `$('answere1').remove()` = Get any `<answere1 />` tags and remove them. `$('<area class="true" shape="circle" coords="145, 175, 40" href="#">').remove()` = Create a new `<area />` element and remove it. Add an id to the answer `<area />` and then `$("#<id>").remove()`

Comment: `$('answere1') != $(answer1)` and `$('<newElement>').remove()` is trying to remove something in the DOM that doesn't exist.

Comment: How is the element `area1` generated, as in `$(area1).appendTo('map');`? Do you mean for that to be $(answere1).appendTo('map');?

Comment: Changed some var names so it would be more clear here tho ask. I edited the question.

Comment: Give the element you want to remove an ID, and use `$("#id").remove()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to remove the element you're clicking on, use:

```
$(".true").click(function() {
    score++;
    $(this).remove();
});
```